# What does the command 'xlsatoms' display?

Tags: linux

I typed in 'xlsatoms' in Terminal and I was givena  list of something called 'interned atoms'. What does that term mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is related to [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), and to its [X Windows System core protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol)

Grossly speaking, an atom is some unique [*symbol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28programming%29) (implemented as an [interned string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), etc...) inside the X11 server [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server). Windows can have properties related to some atom. See also [inter-client communication functions of Xlib](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/), [XSetTextProperty](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XSetTextProperty.html), etc... Read about Xlib [properties and atoms](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/properties-and-atoms.html) & [XInternAtom](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XInternAtom.html).

The [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) defines many conventions using such atoms (e.g. for the [clipboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_%28computing%29)).

So `xlsatoms` is displaying the collection of atoms known to your X11 server.